# How to properly create security groups for instance classes in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-vpc

So right now I have 4 subnets per availability zone: The internet facing "entrypoint" subnet (associated with a load balancer), the generic "service" subnet for internal computation, the "database" subnet for all things data related, and the "external request" subnet for making requests out to the internet. This defines essentially 4 classes of EC2 instances.

I am supposed to now create security groups for these 4 classes of EC2 instances. What I'm wondering is how to do that correctly (I am using terraform).

Can I create 1 security group for "ingress" (incoming) traffic, and a 2nd security group for "egress" (outgoing) traffic, for each class, for each connection type?

So basically, I want this. I want the internet entrypoint to talk to the service. The service can only respond to requests from the internet, it doesn't make any external internet requests itself. The service can talk to the database and the external requesting class. The database can only talk to the service, and the external request can only respond back to the service. The entrypoint can come in as HTTP or HTTPS (or websockets, is that just HTTPS?). It comes in on port 443. This is the load balancer. It then converts the request to HTTP and connects to the compute with port 3000. Should I have a separate port for each different connection type? (So the service layer would have 1 port for the database to respond to like 4000, 1 port for the external request layer to respond to like 5000, etc.). Or does that part matter? Lets say we have the ports thing though.

- sg1 (security group 1): ingress 443 -> 3000 (load balancer -> service)
- sg2: egress 3000 -> internet? is that 0.0.0.0/0? I don't want it to make free requests out, only to connected clients.
- sg3: ingress 3000 -> 4000 (service -> database), specifying the database subnet
- sg3: egress 4000 -> 3000 (database -> service), specifying the service subnet, etc.

Am I on the right track? I am new to this and trying to figure it out. Any guidance would be much appreciated, I've been reading the AWS docs for the past week but there's little in terms of best practices and architecture.

Comment: It is normal practice to leave Outbound rules as "fully open" because you can typically 'trust' the code running on your own system. Therefore, when connecting `ec2 -> database`, put a limiting Inbound rule on the database, but allow the ec2 to have fully-open Outbound settings. This will also allow the EC2 instance to communicate with the Internet if necessary. In high-security situations, you could further lockdown the outbound rules if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [upto 5 individual security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups) per [ENI (Elastic Network Interface)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html). All available rules are evaluated whenever either the inbound or outbound ingress rule is established.

Regarding communication, security group rules establish a tunnel (allowing stateful communication) during any network communication allowing bi-directional communication as long as the initial connection was allowed by the security group.

> Security groups are stateful — if you send a request from your instance, the response traffic for that request is allowed to flow in regardless of inbound security group rules. Responses to allowed inbound traffic are allowed to flow out, regardless of outbound rules.

For example:

- Inbound rule allows SSH on port 22 from a specific IP address, no outbound rules for port 22 exist. A user can safely SSH to the server with no connection issues, but is unable to SSH to another server. Add outbound rules if the server should be able to speak outbound, by default it will be allow all.

From this above example this means if you allow no outbound rules for HTTP/HTTPS only inbound connections over HTTP/HTTPS will allow it to return. Also be aware for patching that you will not be able to download from the internet.

Regarding the source, perhaps rather than specifying subnets you can reference the logical security group name instead. This would mean if a resource in any subnet has that security group attached the target resource would allow inbound access (this only works if the connection is private host to private host).

> The source of the traffic and the destination port or port range. The source can be another security group, an IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR block, a single IPv4 or IPv6 address, or a prefix list ID.

I would recommend trying to keep the resource realm within a single security group (i.e. DB server all in a single security group) primarily to reduce the overhead of management.

More information is available at the [Security groups for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) page.

Comment: "Also be aware for patching that you will not be able to download from the internet." what do you mean here?

Comment: If the outbound for HTTP/HTTPS is missing you would not be able to reach out to the internet for any patches or package updates :)

Comment: Should you have both ingress and egress defined in a single security group, or separated into two, or does it matter?

Comment: It's really a choice, but generally security groups are for a specific server purpose rather than direction of travel. This helps reduce the overhead of management :)